# why is child not detecting change from parent input in angular

Tags: angular

I have a child component

parent.component.html

```
 <child-component (changeVal) = "parentObj"></child-component>
```

parent.component.ts

```
parentObj = {
  someDate = new Date()
}
// function changing the parentObj
callOnClick() {
   this.parentObj.someDate = new Date('20 June 2018'); 
}
```

child component.ts

```
@Input('changeVal')
ngOnChanges() {
 // console i never see
 console.log('parentObj Changed and got me here');
}
```

Why is the onChanges hook not running in this case? I am changing the input value inside the callOnClick method, isn't it supposed to fire when the value of changeVal is changed ?

Comment: Thanks for the simple solution, Ravi. KUDOS!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<child-component (changeVal) = "parentObj"></child-component>
```

`changeVal` is an input in your code, but an output in your HTML. Consider using this instead :

```
<child-component [changeVal] = "parentObj"></child-component>
```

And declare a variable as an input, not your function.

```
@Input() changeVal: any;
```

Comment: Still can't see the console message.

Comment: Declare a variable after your decorator, functions aren't input, especially lifecycle functions

Answer (score 3):

If I'm not mistaken, you're trying to pass an object from parent to child.

`parentObj` is a property. Use property binding using square brackets as follows:

```
<child-component [changeVal] = "parentObj"></child-component>
```

Also, in child.component.ts, you have to provide `@Input()` decorator to a property not a method.

```
    @Input('changeVal') changeVal = {};
    ngOnChanges() {
      // console i never see
      console.log('parentObj Changed and got me here');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use the speard operator " ... " to force change detection

syntax is as follows

this.object = {...this.object};

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).